# Where can I find some podcasts or something similar about the Kinect SDK

Tags: sdk, kinect, podcast, xbox

I want to find out more about programming with the Kinect SDK for windows, so I would like to watch some podcasts or something similar. Where can I find some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Developer Network Channel 9:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectSDKQuickstarts